# R - web scraping with ''load more'' button

Tags: r, web-scraping, load

I am trying to get the data about types of beers and locations where they are most popular from this webpage: https://untappd.com/La_Source

I wrote the code:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link = "https://untappd.com/La_Source"
page = read_html(link)

name = page %>% html_nodes(".user") %>% html_text()
place = page %>% html_nodes("a:nth-child(4)") %>% html_text()
user = page %>% html_nodes(".user") %>% html_text()

user_links = page %>% html_nodes(".user") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://untappd.com/", ., sep="")
  
get_city = function(user_link) {
#  user_link= 'https://untappd.com/user/Linty'
  user_page = read_html(user_link)
  user_city = user_page %>% html_nodes(".location") %>%
    html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
  return(user_city)
}

city = sapply(user_links, FUN = get_city, USE.NAMES = FALSE)  

#brewery = page %>% html_nodes("a:nth-child(3)") %>% html_text()

Beer = data.frame(name, place,user,city, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
write.csv(Beer, "Beer.csv")
```

which works really nicely and gives me needed data. The issue when I try to get more data by ''pressing load more button '' at the bottom of the page. I am not sure how I can do it in R. Any advices ?

Comment: Use something like [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RSelenium) instead. That allows you to interact with the webpage like you were using a web browser and you can write code to push buttons for you. The other option is to use your browsers developer tools to try to see where the data is coming from and see if you can grab the data directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can press the "button show more" with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
url <- "https://untappd.com/La_Source"
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

remDr$executeScript("scroll(0,100000);")

web_Obj_Show_More <- remDr$findElement("css selector", '#slide > div.cont.brewery-page > div > div.box.activity > div > a')
web_Obj_Show_More$clickElement()
```

You can also consider the following approach :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
url <- "https://untappd.com/La_Source"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(15)
doc <- IEApp$Document()

clickEvent <- doc$createEvent("MouseEvent")
clickEvent$initEvent("click", TRUE, FALSE)

web_Obj <- doc$querySelector('#slide > div.cont.brewery-page > div > div.box.activity > div > a')
web_Obj$dispatchEvent(clickEvent)
```